# Struggling parenting BVH motion capture data with existing model correctly

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, motion-capture, bvh

I'm trying to parent (with automatic weights) a mesh that I have to a rig that has been motion captured. However, the rest position (edit mode) of the rig does not match the mesh. Do I have to change the mesh to match the rig because if I change the rig to match the mesh it distorts the animation (specifically, the legs overlap).I go into edit mode and try to match the rig to the human mesh but when I play the animation the legs overlap. Do I have to edit the mesh to match the rig's rest position?

[image: The first picture shows the model in object mode.]

[image: The second shows the rig in edit mode unaltered.]

[image: The third shows the rig after being edited]

[image: And the final picture shows the rig in object mode and the legs are crossed.]